# how to fire addEventListener when javascript change value

Tags: javascript, html

i have a div with some elements.

```
<div>
<input value="" id="MyElement" type="text">
</div>
```

i added to my div the addEventListener like

```
    document.getElementById("MyDiv").addEventListener('change', function (event)
    {
        alert(event)
        var elem = event.target;
    });
```

it's working fine if i change values by keyboard.
but, when i change a value from JS, nothing happen.

for example

```
function test_1()
{
    tmp = document.getElementById("MyElement")
    tmp.value = "new value"
}
```

what i have to do to fire my OnChange?

ok, i solved with

```
document.getElementById("MyDiv").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

as suggest by "Sebastian Simon"
thank you!

Comment: i tried, but fires its event, not came in addEventListener

Comment: @elle0087 What specifically did you try? [Edit] your post. `document.getElementById("MyDiv").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));` will surely work just fine.

Comment: @elle0087, probably you missed `new Event('change')`. Check the working sample in the answer posted. Check and let me know if require further assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i solved with

```
function test_1()
{
    document.getElementById("MyDiv").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}
```

as suggest by "Sebastian Simon" thank you!

so, to be complete, the problem was about apply Select2 on the dropdown.
Select2 doesn't fire native Onchange, but fires its.
that mean "addEventListener" will not fired when your dropdown change value.
to do that, i created on its event a textbox, appended to him, fired the Onchange texbox and than remove it.

for example:

```
            $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({dropdownAutoWidth : true});
            $('.js-example-basic-single').on('change', function (e)
            {
                tmp_div = document.createElement("input");
                e.target.appendChild(tmp_div)
                tmp_div.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
                e.target.removeChild(tmp_div)
            });
<div>
  <input value="" id="MyElement" type="text">
  <select id="cmb_UM1" class="js-example-basic-single select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="select2-data-ctl00_Content_cmb_UM1">
    <option selected="selected" value="" title="" data-select2-id="select2-data-2-vplr"></option>
    <option value=" 1001171997" title=" 1001171997" data-select2-id="select2-data-12-gcgl"> 1001171997</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dispatchEvent` or `fireEvent` as required.

Check [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript) for further details.

Update

Check the below snippet for working sample

```js
document.getElementById("MyDiv").addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    alert(event)
    var elem = event.target;
});

document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    alert(event)
    var elem = event.target;
});


function fnc() {
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "New";
  var event = new Event('change');
    document.getElementById("myInput").dispatchEvent(event);
  document.getElementById("MyDiv").value = "Somethinig";
}
```

```html
<div id="MyDiv">
  hi
</div>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Text" />

<button onclick="fnc()">Click to fire event</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try calling back the first function(used for alert) when entering values with different buttons .

Or you can create another alert when button is clicked to enter values

```js
document.getElementById("MyElement").addEventListener('change', test_2)

function test_2() {
  alert(event)
  var elem = event.target;
};

document.getElementById("MyDiv").addEventListener('click', test_1)

function test_1() {
  tmp = document.getElementById("MyElement");
  tmp.value = "new value";
  test_2();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input value="" id="MyElement" type="text">
  <button id="MyDiv">Try me</button>
</div>
```